# Django ERROR EXTERNAL IP: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.master.loberon.patrick-thomas.de'

Tags: django

```
[Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.master.loberon.patrick-thomas.de'. You may need to add 'www.master.loberon.patrick-thomas.de' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

I'm getting this error in production. The referenced host is **not my domain**.

Django Version: 3.1.2

Comment: You probably want to read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/security/#host-headers-virtual-hosting)

Comment: Thanks, I think someone else is trying to access my site

Comment: Solved by adding to settings.py:
`    'loggers': {
        'django.security.DisallowedHost': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding to settings.py:

```
'loggers': {
    'django.security.DisallowedHost': {
        'handlers': ['null'],
        'propagate': False,
    },
}
```